# ¿Cómo poner el valor de un JSON en DIV - JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

¿Cómo puedo poner el valor de un `JSON` en un input?.
Tengo este código:

```
{"db":{"d_confirmado":49,"d_reservado":30,"d_no_consulta":7,"d_observado":0,"d_institucional":0,"d_club_salud":63,"d_madre_ni":6,"d_cia_seg":9}}
```

y quiero mostrarlo así:

```
$('#db_confirmado').val(db_confirmado);
```

Pero lo que quiero es que haga un recorrido por si existe el `div` con el mismo nombre, entonces que ingrese el valor.

**NOTA:** No quiero escribir todos los `div`, sino que se haga un recorrido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estás usando jQuery, así que podrías utilizar [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) para iterar por los diferentes elementos del objeto. El formato sería el siguiente:

```
$.each(ARRAY_U_OBJETO, function(indice, valor) {
    // operaciones que se aplicarán para cada elemento del array/objeto
});
```

Aqui te dejo un ejemplo con el código que compartiste:

```js
var datos = {"db":{"d_confirmado":49,"d_reservado":30,"d_no_consulta":7,"d_observado":0,"d_institucional":0,"d_club_salud":63,"d_madre_ni":6,"d_cia_seg":9}};

$.each(datos.db, function(indice, valor) {
   console.log(indice + " = " + valor);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Y un ejemplo que rellena los elementos HTML si el ID existe y coincide con el índice:

```js
var datos = {"db":{"d_confirmado":49,"d_reservado":30,"d_no_consulta":7,"d_observado":0,"d_institucional":0,"d_club_salud":63,"d_madre_ni":6,"d_cia_seg":9}};

// variable que contendrá la suma de todos los valores
var suma_total = 0;

$.each(datos.db, function(indice, valor) {
   // solo se escribe el valor si no es cero
   if (valor !=0) { 
     // añade el valor a la suma total
     suma_total += valor;
     $("#" + indice).text(valor); 
   }
});

// muestra el total de la suma
alert("La suma total es " + suma_total);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Confirmado: <span id="d_confirmado"></span><br/>
Reservado: <span id="d_reservado"></span><br/>
Observado: <span id="d_observado"></span><br/>
No consulta: <span id="d_no_consulta"></span>
```

Comment: Gracias, me sirvió y me lo pinto, una consulta si le diera una validación? en caso si es 0 que no me imprima el valor??

Comment: En ese caso solo necesitas un `if`  dentro del `each()`. Algo como esto: `if (valor != 0) { $("#" + indice).text(valor); }`

Comment: @JeanPaul he actualizado la demo para que sólo escriba los valores si no son cero

Comment: Gracias, una ultima consulta, como puedo hacer para sumar todos los "Valor"? y que me muestre en otro DIV ID distinto???

Comment: @JeanPaul he cambiado la demo para que se ajuste a la última consulta. La idea es simple: crear una variable fuera del bucle, y sumarle `valor` en cada iteración del `each`.

Comment: Perfecto, me ayudaste en todo, muchas gracias :)!

Answer (score 2):

Si entendí bien el problema, la solución podría ser así, donde `miJson` es el JSON que pones en la pregunta:

```
var misValores = JSON.parse(miJson);

// recorrer objeto
$.each( misValores.db, function( key, valor ) {

  // detectar si hay un elemento en el DOM con id igual a la llave del JSON
  if ($('#'. key).html().length) {
    $('#' . key).val(valor);
  }

});
```

Comment: No me salio :/ tengo estos input
<input id="d_confirmado" type="text" value="">

Comment: No me marca error, pero no me pone el valor en el id :/

Comment: No lo puedo probar ahora, intenta quitando el método `.html()` dejando solo la propiedad `length`

Answer (score 1):

Si bien aquí te dejo una muestra de como puedes hacerlo sin Librerias externas, esta escrito en JS Nátivo. Puedes modificar el código a tus necesidades.

```js
//Estos son los datos que tu tienes
var da = '{"db":{"d_confirmado":49,"d_reservado":30,"d_no_consulta":7,"d_observado":0,"d_institucional":0,"d_club_salud":63,"d_madre_ni":6,"d_cia_seg":9}}';
//Les damos un parse con JSON
var data = JSON.parse(da);

//Iteramos los datos con un for in
for(var a in data){
var b = data[a]; 
  for(var c in b){ //Iteramos sobre los posibles campos; d_confirmado, d_reservado, etc. etc.
    var d = b[c];
    var inp = document.querySelector("#"+c); //Buscamos en el documento el input que tenga ID; d_cofirmado, etc. etc.
    (inp) ? (inp.value = d):false; // Si existe el campo, le asignamos el valor
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="d_confirmado" /><br/>
<input id="algun otro" />
```